# 1 min countdown js timer loop not working

Tags: javascript, timer

I created 1 min time loop for my website. If the timer ends it will show some results.after that timer will start again 1:00. But sometimes error comming like, something time going very high (2 min ,50min, 5sec, 1sec ). It not stay in 1min loop. Please help me sir to fix this error.

Code:

```js
function timerFunc(date) {

  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();
  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    var forseconds = prependZero(seconds);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "0" + minutes + ": " + forseconds;

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance <= 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
function prependZero(number) {
  if (number <= 9)
    return "0" + number;
  else
    return number;
}
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Comment: where do you call `timerFunc`?

Comment: also `distance` will pretty much mostly be negative.

Comment: functionn createSession(){

      var uid = "<?php echo $uid;?>";
      var dte = "<?php echo $latTime;?>";
    var stime = "<?php echo $stoptime;?>";
    
    

    timerFunc(uid, dte);
   }

Comment: Called before the timefunction